# How to strip uncommon parts of filenames and have the unique parts

Tags: bash, scripts, files, grep

Here is the file names I have;

```
cpu-system-2016-05-06  
cpu-system-2017-05-08  
cpu-wait-2017-05-08
cpu-wait-2016-05-06
cpu-wait-2017-05-07
cpu-interrupt-2017-05-08  
cpu-interrupt-2016-05-07  
cpu-softirq-2017-05-07
cpu-softirq-2017-05-08  
cpu-softirq-2017-05-06
```

I would like to parse the names via `-201` and take the first part into account in order to receive such output;

```
cpu-system 
cpu-wait
cpu-interrupt
cpu-softirq
```

What would be the optimal solution?

Comment: Is this a file containing filenames or just filenames?

Comment: Ahh, it's a directory that contains those files let's say /cpu-0

Answer (score 2):

I won't say this is "the optimal solution", but given

```
$ ls cpu*
cpu-interrupt-2016-05-07  cpu-softirq-2017-05-06  cpu-softirq-2017-05-08  cpu-system-2017-05-08  cpu-wait-2017-05-07
cpu-interrupt-2017-05-08  cpu-softirq-2017-05-07  cpu-system-2016-05-06   cpu-wait-2016-05-06    cpu-wait-2017-05-08
```

then

```
$ ls cpu* | cut -d- -f1,2 | uniq
cpu-interrupt
cpu-softirq
cpu-system
cpu-wait
```

Comment: Hmm I'd suggest quoting the delimeter(leaving them could result in leaving them when they are needed)

Answer (score 2):

Considering any possible filename, from that directory:

```
printf '%s\0' cpu-*-201* | \
  awk -F'-' 'BEGIN{RS="\0"} $3~/^201/ {a[$1"-"$2]} END{for(i in a) print i}'
```

- `printf '%s\0' cpu-*-201*` prints the filenames separated by NUL
- `awk` sets the record separator as NUL, and put the `-` separated first two fields (with a `-` in between) as key of the associative array `a`, if the third field starts with `201`. In the end, we are just printing the array keys with  `{a[$1"-"$2]} END{for(i in a) print i}`

If you want, you can get rid of the array and leverage `sort` after printing the first two fields separated by `-`:

```
printf '%s\0' cpu-*-201* | \
  awk -F'-' 'BEGIN{RS="\0"} $3~/^201/ {print $1"-"$2}' | sort -u
```

---

Assuming no unusual filename, there are many options, all taking help from `sort -u` to get uniqueness:

- `grep`, with PCRE:

  ```
  printf '%s\n' cpu-*-201* | grep -Po '^.*(?=-201)' | sort -u
  ```
- `sed`:

  ```
  printf '%s\n' cpu-*-201* | sed -E 's/^(.*)-201.*/\1/' | sort -u
  ```
- `awk`:

  ```
  printf '%s\n' cpu-*-201* | awk -F'-' '$3~/^201/ {a[$1"-"$2]} END{for(i in a) print i}'
  printf '%s\n' cpu-*-201* | awk -F'-' '$3~/^201/ {print $1"-"$2}' | sort -u
  ```
- `cut`, *assuming stable fields, this is blindly getting first two fields*:

  ```
  printf '%s\n' cpu-*-201* | cut -d- -f1,2 | sort -u
  ```

---

**Example:**

```
% printf '%s\n' cpu-*-201*
cpu-interrupt-2016-05-07
cpu-interrupt-2017-05-08
cpu-softirq-2017-05-06
cpu-softirq-2017-05-07
cpu-softirq-2017-05-08
cpu-system-2016-05-06
cpu-system-2017-05-08
cpu-wait-2016-05-06
cpu-wait-2017-05-07
cpu-wait-2017-05-08

% printf '%s\0' cpu-*-201* | awk -F'-' 'BEGIN{RS="\0"} $3~/^201/ {a[$1"-"$2]} END{for(i in a) print i}'
cpu-softirq
cpu-interrupt
cpu-wait
cpu-system

% printf '%s\0' cpu-*-201* | awk -F'-' 'BEGIN{RS="\0"} $3~/^201/ {print $1"-"$2}' | sort -u
cpu-interrupt
cpu-softirq
cpu-system
cpu-wait

% printf '%s\n' cpu-*-201* | grep -Po '^.*(?=-201)' | sort -u
cpu-interrupt
cpu-softirq
cpu-system
cpu-wait

% printf '%s\n' cpu-*-201* | sed -E 's/^(.*)-201.*/\1/' | sort -u
cpu-interrupt
cpu-softirq
cpu-system
cpu-wait

% printf '%s\n' cpu-*-201* | awk -F'-' '$3~/^201/ {a[$1"-"$2]} END{for(i in a) print i}'
cpu-interrupt
cpu-softirq
cpu-system
cpu-wait

% printf '%s\n' cpu-*-201* | awk -F'-' '$3~/^201/ {print $1"-"$2}' | sort -u
cpu-interrupt
cpu-softirq
cpu-system
cpu-wait

% printf '%s\n' cpu-*-201* | cut -d- -f1,2 | sort -u
cpu-interrupt
cpu-softirq
cpu-system
cpu-wait
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Perl solution

We can use Perl to extract the wanted part before `-201` substring, and store items into a hash, where each extracted string will be a key value.

```
$ perl -ne '($var=$_)=~s/^(.*)-201(.*)/\1/g;$hash{$var}+=1; END{ do{print }for keys %hash}'  input.txt                   
cpu-system
cpu-softirq
cpu-wait
cpu-interrupt
```

Once processing is done, as a result only unique values will be left as keys, although note that they won't be in specific sorted order(so if you want sorted output, pipe the output to `sort` command)